# CSS Form Styling #2

Tags: css, forms, xhtml

I have seen forms that can do this without using `<br />` etc.

Here's my form:

```
<form id="staff-login" name="staff-login" action="/staff/login/" method="POST">
    <label for="staff-login-email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="staff-login-email" name="email" value="" />
    <label for="staff-login-address">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="staff-login-password" name="password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="staff-login-submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

And an example of what I'm taking about:
http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/4879/43201622.gif

All the examples I can Google insert extra `<div>`s and mess with the code, I'm wondering if there is a way with the code I have (or if you can structure my code "better") to achieve what I need?

Comment: I think css styles Padding and Margins can help you...

Comment: You just asked another question concerning this exact problem, and you're still wanting other people to solve A MINOR change in the layout? It's perfectly legal to use your own head once in a while.

Comment: In the time you took to write that, you could have contributed to finding a solution to the first one. Obviously because there are solutions for this, and not for the first, the questions are different.

Comment: For your first question don't exist solutions? Should it be closed then? Have you had a look at e.g. http://en.wordpress.com/wp-login.php ?

Comment: I think what Tor Valamo wants to express is, that you should understand the basics of styling a form from your first question and be able to apply these here. Basically both question ask for styling forms. Learn it once, apply it to every other case.

Answer (score 1):

using css, float your label to the left. Also, make your input elements blocks with a decent margin...

```
label { float: left; width: 200px; }
input { margin-left: 220px; display: block; }
input.staff-login-submit { margin-left: 500px }
```

I've just guessed at a few numbers for the margins, so tweak as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but the submit button doesn't goto the right, and a text-align: right; fixed the labels :)

Answer (score 0):

`<label>` and `<input>` are inline elements. Either you use `<br />` (which is totally ok) or you specify them as block elements via CSS.

You can learn more about [inline and block elements](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline.php).